# How to tell if the file supplied really is a registry hive

Tags: c#, .net, windows, registry

I'm doing some work with registry hives, and I need to know if the file the user supplies the program with really is a registry hive. Short of attempting to mount it, how can I tell if the file really is a registry hive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question, upon digging around, there is a call that is part of the [Offline Registry Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210757%28VS.85%29.aspx) that will attempt to validate the hive and report back whether it was successful or not, but it's part of Win32/COM

[OROpenHive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210770%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Sounds like what you want to do, just no direct .NET implementation of it

Comment: pinvoke is fine. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Very quick preliminary check: the file must start with "regf" signature.